# Anaconda (latest version) not launching with python 3.6 on windows 10

Tags: anaconda, spyder, python-3.6

I had Python 2.7 anaconda running perfectly fine, but when I uninstalled it and installed anaconda for 3.6 python on windows 10, it's not launching, neither Spyder is opening.
the following traceback I got from anaconda prompt.
I have deleted .lock files suggested in some earlier posts.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Being_Rohit\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py", line 3, in 
<module>
import conda.cli
File "C:\Users\Being_Rohit\Anaconda3\lib\site-
packages\conda\cli\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
from .main import main  # NOQA
File "C:\Users\Being_Rohit\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", 
line 42, in <module>
from argparse import SUPPRESS
File "C:\Users\Being_Rohit\Anaconda3\lib\argparse.py", line 89, in <module>
import re as _re
File "C:\Users\Being_Rohit\Anaconda3\lib\re.py", line 142, in <module>
class RegexFlag(enum.IntFlag):
AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'
```

Comment: It seems conda is broken. Please try to uninstall and reinstall again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the re module trying to import enum.IntFlag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47878060/why-is-the-re-module-trying-to-import-enum-intflag)