# Why is the re module trying to import enum.IntFlag?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydev, development-environment, archlinux

How is it possible that a core module is importing a non-existent name from another core module?

Specifically, the `re` module importing `enum.IntFlag`

---

***Ways to Reproduce***

It can be reproduced by launching an interpreter and attempting the import, running a program that depends on `enum.IntFlag` such as `pip`, viewing the interpreter settings page in Eclipse, using the text editor, running the interactive console in PyDev, ...

Directly importing

```
from enum import IntFlag

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'IntFlag'
```

Run a dependant program (pip)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 4, in <module>
    import re
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 142, in <module>
    class RegexFlag(enum.IntFlag):
AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'
```

Viewing the Python Interpreter settings in Eclipse also produces the above traceback (in the window the interpreter settings would be in).

`Preferences =:> PyDev =:> Interpreters =:> Python Interpreter`

Also the text editor doesn't recognise a print statement.

Also, when I run the console interpreter (eg: `Ctrl+Alt+Enter`, eclipse fails with a popup showing this:

> 'Create Interactive Console' has encountered a problem.
>
> Error initializing console.
>
> *Error Details*

Click the *Error Details* button:

```
Error initializing console.
Unexpected error connecting to console.
Failed to recive suitable Hello response from pydevconsole. Last msg received: Console already exited with value: 1 while waiting for an answer.

Command Line used:  /usr/bin/python3.6 -u /usr/lib/eclipse/../../../home/scott/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_4.7.1_155965261_linux_gtk_x86_64/plugins/org.python.pydev_6.2.0.201711281614/pysrc/pydevconsole.py 44633 43575 44633 43575

Environment:
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/cuda/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/opt/jython/bin/:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
XAUTHORITY=/tmp/xauth-1000-_0
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share:/usr/share:/usr/local/share
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=KDE
QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=0
MAIL=/var/spool/mail/scott
MOZ_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins
QT_LINUX_ACCESSIBILITY_ALWAYS_ON=1
SESSION_MANAGER=local/scott-pc:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/976,unix/scott-pc:/tmp/.ICE-unix/976
LOGNAME=scott
PAM_KWALLET5_LOGIN=/run/user/1000/kwallet5.socket
PWD=/home/scott
XCURSOR_THEME=Azenis
PYPATH=/code/scott/Py/Path
PYTHONPATH=/home/scott/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_4.7.1_155965261_linux_gtk_x86_64/plugins/org.python.pydev_6.2.0.201711281614/pysrc/pydev_sitecustomize:/mnt/ssdata/scott/code/Py/Path:/home/scott:/usr/lib/python3.6/Tools/scripts:/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload:/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages:/usr/lib/python3.6
KDE_SESSION_VERSION=5
SHELL=/bin/bash
KDE_MULTIHEAD=false
KDE_FULL_SESSION=true
GTK_MODULES=canberra-gtk-module
GDK_SCALE=1
DATA=/data/scott/
XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session1
PYDYNLOAD=/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload
VM=/vm/scott/
XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=KDE
SHLVL=1
PYSITE=/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages
OXYGEN_DISABLE_INNER_SHADOWS_HACK=1
PYVER=3.6
KDE_SESSION_UID=1000
XFILESEARCHPATH=/usr/dt/app-defaults/%L/Dt
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
XDG_SESSION_ID=c2
XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
DISPLAY=:0
PYTHONSTARTUP=/usr/lib/python3.6/startup_hook.py
GTK_RC_FILES=/etc/gtk/gtkrc:/home/scott/.gtkrc:/home/scott/.config/gtkrc
ECLIPSE_HOME=/usr/lib/eclipse
XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user
XCURSOR_SIZE=56
LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=0
DESKTOP_SESSION=/usr/share/xsessions/plasma
GDK_CORE_DEVICE_EVENTS=1
USER=scott
GTK2_RC_FILES=/etc/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:/home/scott/.gtkrc-2.0:/home/scott/.config/gtkrc-2.0
XDG_SEAT=seat0
CODE=/code/scott/
GS_LIB=/home/scott/.fonts
PYSCRIPTS=/usr/lib/python3.6/Tools/scripts
NLSPATH=/usr/dt/lib/nls/msg/%L/%N.cat
XDG_VTNR=1
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
HOME=/home/scott
PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8
PYDEV_UMD_ENABLED=true
PYDEV_UMD_NAMELIST=guidata,guiqwt
PYDEV_UMD_VERBOSE=true
```

---

***Progress***

in the standard library version `/usr/lib/python3.6/enum.py`,
the name `enum.IntFlag` exists in `enum.__all__`

Is `enum` being imported from the standard library version?

```
import enum
print(enum.__file__)
# /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/enum/__init__.py
```

It is importing from `/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/enum/__init__.py` I checked that file and there is no `IntFlag`. Also, it's a package init rather than a single file.

There is no `/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/enum/enum.py`. There is a `README` file that says that this is ver 3.4.

I could replace the contents of `__init__.py` with `enum.py`

I could delete the `site-packages/enum` directory

---

***Solution***

There is another `enum` module, a python3.4 compatibility package, that was masking the module version in the standard library.

python34 compatibility package: `/usr/lib/python3.6/enum/__init__.py`

the standard library module: `/usr/lib/python3.6/enum.py`.

I deleted the directories:

```
mkdir enumbackup
cd enumbackup
sudo mv /usr/lib/python3.6/enum .
sudo mv /usr/lib/python3.6/enumenum34-1.1.6.dist-info .
```

Now, `enum.__file__` shows `/usr/lib/python3.6/enum.py` as it should and everything works.

```
from enum import IntFlag
## works
```

Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Restore from backup. We can't tell what's going on from just this, and diagnosing your system over a long back-and-forth tech support "try this" "okay that didn't work" "show me the output of this command" "what's in this file" isn't the kind of thing we do here.

Comment: You seem to be trying to edit your question to be more on-topic, but what you're turning it into is easily answerable by ctrl-F-ing for `enum` in the [`re` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-contents). It's trying to import `enum.IntFlag` because it needs to use `enum.IntFlag`. That's usually why code imports things.

Comment: I've tried lots to figure out the problem. It's getting in the way of my development.. I'm kinda at a loss debugging it and am hoping that someone in the community can point me in the right directions.

Comment: I checked the re docs as well as `/usr/lib/python3.6/enum.py` and both of the names exist. it's even in `enum.__all__`, but it doesn't import.. see additional `ImportError` I'm about to edit into the question

Comment: Unfortunately my issue wasn't solved by searching the re docs. I am getting the description of the topic a bit more clearly in newer edits.

Comment: @Inversus. Have you checked to see if there's another module named `enum` on your python path? What is the output of this: `import enum; print(enum.__file__)`?

Comment: @ekhumoro it is importing from `/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/enum/__init__.py` I checked that file and there is no `IntFlag`. Also, it's a package init rather than a single file.. hmm

Comment: @Inversus. Python got stdlib support for `enum` with version 3.4. Before that, the [enum pypi package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum/0.4.6) might have been installed as a dependency. Assuming the stdlib `enum` is backwards compatible, you could probably safely remove the site-packages version.

Comment: @ekhumoro is it safe to do that manually? pip doesn't run because of this issue.. so what, delete the `/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/enum` directory?

Comment: @Inversus. What distro package manager do you use? I would firstly check to see if it was installed as a dependency of some other package on your system. If so, use your package manager to remove it; if not, remove it manually. You can always reinstall with pip if something breaks.

Comment: @ekhumoro there it is `python2-enum34`. It has 22 dependencies, all other python2 libraries except for one: ceph. oh also `python2-cryptography`.all this python2 cruft lol

Comment: @Inversus. That is a **python2** package, though - so you don't want to touch that. Is there a **python3** enum package? I would guess not, now that your system is using python-3.6.

Comment: uninstalled python2-enum34 but the exception still occurs. also, package manager: Octopi / pacman. Just found out about yaourt

Comment: @ekhumoro yea, the equivalent python3 package would be called `python-enum` but it doesn't exist. I guess that's because as you mention the stdlib support for enums being better. I'm going to try manually deleting that directory next. Might work

Comment: @ekhumoro thanks!!! Everything works now. Ahhhhhh. I'll update my question with the things I used but you deserve to write up the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should check to see if there's another module named `enum` on your python path that is shadowing the stdlib `enum` module. To do that, you can do:

```
import enum
print(enum.__file__)
```

If that doesn't match the `python3` stdlib module path, you should try to remove it. Ideally, you should use whatever package manager your system uses to uninstall it, as it it might be a dependency of some other package. But if that isn't possible, you can just try removing it manually.

Comment: There was a python3.4 compatibility module at `/usr/lib/python3.6/enum/__init__.py` that was interfering with the standard library module at `/usr/lib/python3.6/enum.py`. Manually deleted the directories `/usr/lib/python3.6/enum` and `/usr/lib/python3.6/enumenum34-1.1.6.dist-info` and now `enum.__file__` shows `/usr/lib/python3.6/enum.py` as it should and everything works. I love it when that happens.

Comment: @you saved my day